# Routes are matched incorrectly when nesting lazy loaded modules

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

In trying to reduce the initial download size of my application, I have been attempting to separate it in to modules. I've hit a snag though, since I'm having trouble with the route matching.

I've created an example:

**app/app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'main', loadChildren: '../app/main/main.module#MainModule' }
];
```

**app/main/main-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'secondary', loadChildren: '../../app/secondary/secondary.module#SecondaryModule' },
    { path: 'a/:id', component: AComponent }
];
```

**app/secondary/secondary-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'a/:id', component: BComponent }
];
```

`AComponent` is declared in the `MainModule` and `BComponent` in the `SecondaryModule`

Now I would expect that urls of the form
`/main/secondary/a/someID` would load the `SecondaryModule` and show the `BComponent`, but rather the `AComponent` is shown. The lazy loading does work though.

Interestingly enough, if I change my routes by removing the `/:id`, `/main/secondary/a` will give me a *Cannot match any routes* error.

Comment: just starts your path as an absolute path, not relative for loadchildren. `app/whateveryouwant/my-module#MyModule`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I highly doubt this is the problem. Using an absolute paths gives me errors about not being able to locate the module.

Comment: I've done that a lot of times. You can find examples on this repo if you want :) https://gitlab.com/linagora/petals-cockpit

Comment: As far as I can see the routes on there are relative as well. 
Case in point: `loadChildren: './features/login/login.module#LoginModule',`.

Additionally, the routing setup doesn't seem to share any similarities to what I am trying to accomplish here. Am I missing something?

Comment: Weird, I was pretty sure it wasn't like that before but I might be wrong and there E2E tests so pretty sure it's fine. Sorry not sure how to help you much more :/

Comment: Do you have found a solution i have exactly the same issue. Angular match with the bad component if sub route are the same. It seems to ignore main route

Comment: No, sorry I gave up on this. At least for the time being. I wish you the best of luck in figuring it out. If you do find a solution or different way to accomplish the same, I'd be very interested in it though. :)

Comment: @HenrikH.Sørensen Consider creating separate modules for each lazy loaded route even though they may be related in functionality